# Symfony traits and Doctrine annotations not working as expected

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, traits

my goal is to create reusable traits for common tasks in symfony2 applications. For example I want to have sluggable trait, when added to my entity, automatically slug field and listener is added to update every entity. My problem comes when trying to inherit doctrine annotations from traits.

Take this example:

```
/**
 * @UniqueEntity("name")
 */
trait Sluggable {
    /**
    * @Assert\NotBlank()
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
    */
    protected $name;
}
```

and I'm using it like this

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="seller")
 */
class Seller implements SluggableInterface {
    use Sluggable;
}
```

and when I try to create `Seller` from form, the `@UniqueEntity("name")` is not working and the validation is not working. I have to manually add it in the `Seller` class in order to work and I don't want that. Thanks.

Comment: A class does not inherit annotations from a trait. But you probably may use [doctrine extensions: sluggable](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md) to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes don't inherit "class-level" annotations from used traits, only from their methods and properties. The doctrine annotation reader doesn't support this.

(The symfony validator component uses "doctrine/annotations" to read the annotations so it's most likely affected too.)

See https://github.com/doctrine/phpcr-odm/issues/639

There's a [PR](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/pull/58) for this but it hasn't been merged yet so you're out of luck.